# creating a multi_models signup page for Yii2 and saving that info in session

Tags: php, session, yii2

I am working on a personal Yii2 project and I am stuck! I don't know how to :

- create a sing up page which has a form to create two related models (Organization & Employee ) and use a third one (Employee_Role)
- Store these info in a session and use that session later.

**General Scenario :**

Admin signups by filling :
an Organization name
and username & password & email (for the Admin employee)

if the values are valid then the system creates "Organization" with an auto_generated organization_id.

Then, System creates "Employee" (which will need organization_id and assign this user to Admin "Employee_Role")

Then, the system keeps the following info in session: (organization_id, employee_id, role_id, timestamp ) and takes the user to admin home page.

Note, I am keeping the Models in the Common folder and the Controllers in the front-end and so should be the Views.

I appreciate your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a general outline of what you can do to solve your problem. You will need to add the actual fields to the form for both Organization and Employee.

The controller action:

```
public function actionSignup() {
    $post = Yii::$app->request->post();

    $organization = new Organization();
    $employee = new Employee();

    // we try to load both models with the info we get from post
    if($organization->load($organization) && $employee->load($organization)) {
        // we begin a db transaction
        $transaction = $organization->db->beginTransaction();

        try {
            // Try to save the organization
            if(!$organization->save()) {
                throw new \Exception( 'Saving Organization Error' );
            }

            // Assign the organization id and other values to the employee
            $employee->organization_id = $organization->id;
            ...

            // Try to save the employee
            if(!$employee->save()) {
                throw new \Exception( 'Saving Employee Error' );
            }

            // We use setFlash to set values in the session.
            // Important to add a 3rd param as false if you want to access these values without deleting them.
            // But then you need to manually delete them using removeFlash('organization_id')
            // You can use getFlash('organization_id'); somewhere else to get the value saved in the session.
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('organization_id', $organization->id)
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('employee_id', $employee->id)
            ...

            // we finally commit the db transaction
            $transaction->commit();
            return $this->redirect(['somewhere_else']);
        }
        catch(\Exception e) {
            // If we get any exception we do a rollback on the db transaction
            $transaction->rollback();
        }
    }

    return $this->render('the_view', [
        'organization' => $organization,
        'employee' => $employee,
    ]);
}
```

The view file:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin() ?>

    <?= $form->field($organization, 'some_organization_field') ?>

    <!-- More Fields -->

    <?= $form->field($employee, 'some_employee_field') ?>

    <!-- More Fields -->

    <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```